# How to pass parameters from drawer to view in which drawer is set

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have question. How should I provide parameters to main view from drawer. Is it possible? So I'm using drawer from native-base, and I have very unusual need to send two parameters choosen inside drawer (picker lists) to view in which this drawer is set?

So navigation over drawer is created by

```
onPress={() => this.go("DrawerClose")}
onPress={() => this.go("DrawerOpen")}
```

I checked inside DrawerNavigator this comments doesn't exist.

```
const MainNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Home }
});
```

So this is used only to animation or sth like that.
I've tried to set parameters by sending them in this way:

```
 onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerClose", {val1: this.state.selected1, val2: this.state.selected2})}
```

But I think they are not passed forward correctly.
Ano thoughts?